# If Else Statment not working properly

Tags: javascript, extjs, if-statement

I have an if-else statement and have put certain conditions on it. I have two textfields and have an if-else statement to populate one of the textfields based on my input in the other textfield. I have it where if the user enters 'TS' then it sets a value of 'TP' in the other tetfield. That is working just fine. However, I also want to set it where if the user enters 'TS' and then enters a different value for the 'TP' to be blank. I cannot get that part to work in my if-else statement.

```
if (cbRAType.getValue()=='TS'){
    tfRAPA.setValue('TP');
    if (tfRAItem.getValue()!='') {
        tfRAItemSuf.enable(); tfRAItemSuf.setReadOnly(false);
    }
    else {
        tfRAPA.setValue(''); tfRAItemSuf.setValue(''); tfRAItemSuf.disable(); tfRAItemSuf.setReadOnly(true);
    }
}
```

It does not execute tfRAPA.setValue(''); but runs everything else just fine.

Comment: and what whould return "tfRAItem.getValue()" ? it probably is never empty string

Comment: What are the symptoms that tell you it's not hitting  tfRAPA.setValue('')?

Comment: What's the playframework tag doing here?

Comment: I am just trying to say that if cbRAType is anything other than 'TS' then make tfRAPA value blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just mixed up brackets

```
if (cbRAType.getValue()=='TS'){
    tfRAPA.setValue('TP');
    if (tfRAItem.getValue()!='') {
        tfRAItemSuf.enable(); tfRAItemSuf.setReadOnly(false);
    }
} else {
        tfRAPA.setValue(''); tfRAItemSuf.setValue(''); tfRAItemSuf.disable(); tfRAItemSuf.setReadOnly(true);
}
```

Comment: should OP play "find the difference" ?